# Android error converting result java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am trying to create a simple login and registration activity in Android.
I am getting the errors

> Error converting result java.lang.nullpointerexception,error parsing
>   data org.json.JSONException.

Below is my code :
JSONPARSER

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                    List<NameValuePair> params) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {

                    // check for request method
                    if(method == "POST"){
                            // request method is POST
                            // defaultHttpClient
                            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                            is = httpEntity.getContent();

                    }else if(method == "GET"){
                            // request method is GET
                            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                            url += "?" + paramString;
                            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                            is = httpEntity.getContent();
                    }                      


            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;

    }
```

}

USERFUNCTIONS:

```
public class UserFunctions {


private JSONParser jsonParser;

// Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp 
// use http://10.0.2.2/ to connect to your localhost ie http://localhost/
private static String loginURL = "http://49.249.85.221/android_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://49.249.85.221/android_api/";

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";

// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    String method=new String();
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(loginURL,method, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param name
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    String method=new String();
    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(registerURL,method, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function get Login status
 * */
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    int count = db.getRowCount();
    if(count > 0){
        // user logged in
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Function to logout user
 * Reset Database
 * */
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    db.resetTables();
    return true;
}
```

}

REGISTERACTIVITY:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";


    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        if (params.length != 3)
            return null;
        JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
        return json;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        // check for login response
        try {
            if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    // user successfully registred
                    // Store user details in SQLite Database
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                    // Clear all previous data in database
                    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                    // Launch Dashboard Screen
                    Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                    // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                    dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(dashboard);
                    // Close Registration Screen
                    finish();
                }else{
                    // Error in registration
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            new MyAsyncTask().execute(name, email, password);
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

When I ran debugger it pointed to the line `if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null)`
in RegisterActivity. I am clueless as to where I might be wrong. Please guide me on this.

LOGCAT:

```
10-28 22:40:27.422: D/dalvikvm(373): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 78K, 52% free 2599K/5379K,   external 897K/1038K, paused 190ms
10-28 22:40:32.000: W/KeyCharacterMap(373): No keyboard for id 0
10-28 22:40:32.000: W/KeyCharacterMap(373): Using default keymap:     /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-28 22:40:45.879: E/Buffer Error(373): Error converting result    java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 22:40:45.899: E/Buffer Error(373): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 22:40:45.983: E/JSON Parser(373): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-28 22:40:45.989: D/AndroidRuntime(373): Shutting down VM
10-28 22:40:45.989: W/dalvikvm(373): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.example.androidhive.RegisterActivity$1.onClick (RegisterActivity.java:112)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at c om.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 10-28 22:40:46.309: E/JSON Parser(373): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-28 22:40:50.289: I/Process(373): Sending signal. PID: 373 SIG: 9
```

The main issue is resolved after implementing the solution suggested by Martin.
I am facing some other errors now. LOGCAT is attached below.

```
   10-28 23:17:19.183: D/dalvikvm(449): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 78K, 52% free 2599K/5379K, external 897K/1038K, paused 232ms
  10-28 23:17:23.259: W/KeyCharacterMap(449): No keyboard for id 0
  10-28 23:17:23.269: W/KeyCharacterMap(449): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
  10-28 23:17:46.379: E/Buffer Error(449): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
  10-28 23:17:46.389: E/Buffer Error(449): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
  10-28 23:17:46.389: E/JSON Parser(449): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
  10-28 23:17:46.409: E/JSON Parser(449): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: can you post your logcat

Comment: @Satyen: 10-28 22:40:45.879: E/Buffer Error(373): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 22:40:45.899: E/Buffer Error(373): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 22:40:45.983: E/JSON Parser(373): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-28 22:40:45.989: D/AndroidRuntime(373): Shutting down VM
10-28 22:40:45.989: W/dalvikvm(373): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 22:40:46.049: E/AndroidRuntime(373):

Comment: If you want help, please edit your question with your full logcat from the crash. It is too hard to read in a comment (especially unformatted) and you are missing some relevant parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be because the key not even exist, do this before calling json.getString("key"); method:

```
JSONObject json = yourJSON;
if(json != null && !json.isNull(KEY_SUCCESS)){
   //Wahetever you need
   String value = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
   if(value != null && value.length > 0){
       //You will fall here only if there's a value...
   }
}
```

Notice that you first need to make sure that the key actually exist, otherway it could throw a JSONException...

Hope this helps...

Regards!

Comment: FYI, I have added the code as below:
if(json != null && !json.isNull(KEY_SUCCESS)){
                    //Wahetever you need
                    json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                 }
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){

Comment: No, if that's the case the NullPonterException is happening on Integer.parseInt(res),which means, you are not receiving any value on KEY_SUCCESS

Comment: Well, the only way is to avoid the nullpointerexception as shown in my edited answer, but if you are always getting null, means there's a problem with the data you are receiving...

Comment: OKay, Thanks a lot for your help. Will try this and let you know.

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks a lot!!!
I am facing Buffer error and JSON Parser error now. 
Will have to debug it